# How to force tds to get max width from the corresponding th?

Tags: html, css

I've got a table in which every `th` has the following style:

```
width: 100px;
max-width: 100px;
```

And everything would be ok but one `td` has a long e-mail adress without `-` and the `th` is more than `100px` width. Is there any way to force `tds` to get the `max-width` from their corresponding `ths`?

EDIT:

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CX7T9/

Comment: set min-width:100px; max-width: 150px; to email th and delete width:100px

Comment: @GytisŠk This doesn't work. `th` has `min-width` 100px and `max-width` 100px and it still has 150px because of one `td`.

Comment: If you can please provide with code.

Comment: @eomeroff jsFiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to add styles to tds, you can apply all styles related to with, from tds to ths, plus add `word-break:break-all;` Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

I have edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CX7T9/1/